# Issues with adding new rows to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Apologies if the formatting on this is strange, it's the first time I've posted anything. I've created a multi-index data frame in Python, which works fine:

```
arrays = [['one','one', 'two', 'two'],
          ['A','B','A','B']]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
mindex = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples)
s = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randn(4), index=mindex, columns=(['Values']))
s
```

This works fine, except that I think I should be able to add new rows by simply typing

```
s['Values'].loc[('Three', 'A')] = 1
s['Values'].loc[('Three','B')]= 2
```

This returns no error message, and I can check it has worked by entering

```
s['Values'].loc[('Three', 'A')]
```

Which gives me 1. So all as expected. 
However, I can't see the 'Three' data in Jupyter notebook - if simply type

```
s
```

then it only shows me the original one, two, A & B rows. This is probably because the new row is not the index:

```
s.index
```

returns

```
MultiIndex(levels=[['one', 'two'], ['A', 'B']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1]])
```

Can anyone please give me a hint as to what's going on here? I'd like rows I subsequently add to appear in the index. Should I be using the .append function instead? It seems a bit cumbersome and other posts have recommended using the .loc approach above to add rows.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need select column(s) in function [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
s.loc[('Three', 'A'), 'Values'] = 1
s.loc[('Three', 'B'), 'Values'] = 2
print (s)
           Values
one   A -0.808372
      B  0.904552
two   A -0.443619
      B  1.157234
Three A  1.000000
      B  2.000000

print (s.index)

MultiIndex(levels=[['one', 'two', 'Three'], ['A', 'B']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]])
```

because your solution add values to column (`Series`), but not to `DataFrame`:

```
s['Values'].loc[('Three', 'A')] = 1

print (s['Values'])
one    A   -0.808372
       B    0.904552
two    A   -0.443619
       B    1.157234
Three  A    1.000000
Name: Values, dtype: float64

print (s)
         Values
one A -0.808372
    B  0.904552
two A -0.443619
    B  1.157234
```